# extract the special symbol from string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me how can i solve

extract the special symbol from string in oracle

Comment: First read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by extract? You can find a certain character in a column of a table like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableX
WHERE ColumnX LIKE '%A%'
```

Comment: Its not like ,suppose this is my string :-   *Stack@123#12over*
I want extract from this string only *@#* 
so how can i do it..........

Answer (score 0):

```
select  regexp_replace(mystr,[a-zA-Z0-9]) from mytable
```

Comment: @ParasramPawar, was that helpfull?

Comment: I dont understant it but i want like this 
Suppose this is my string :-   *Stack@123#12over*
I want extract from this string only *@#* 
so how can i do it..........

Comment: @ParasramPawar, great. Since this is a correct answer please mark it as such